# Tricky situation with affiliation

Tags: publications, ethics, interpersonal-issues

I would like to hear an advice for a slightly complicated situation.
I'm currently a postdoc working on a revolutionary project during the last year. During this year, my boss gave me a real hard time and managed to sabotage a future job that I found even after it has been confirmed. His point that I should perform 'his request' and not the project that I had in mind (although, it is clear to me that the project he asked cannot be done).

According to my judgement, my boss's project cannot be done and therefore I was working both on the original project as well on my interest (although this created a huge delay in the preparation time of the original project).

Currently, the project is mostly done and should be published soon after my affiliation is over. However, I left jobless due to the action of my boss, and had horrible time throughout the writing process.

My question is in what way would you express you inconvenience. I actually prefer to publish this paper with no affiliation rather than publishing it under an abusive institute. What would be your advice?

Comment: did you take the postdoc position to develop a specific project or to follow your ideas? why did you not resign from the project when you realized it was not doable?

Comment: how did your boss left you jobless? did they fire you or did the contract expired?

Comment: The question in its current form is not useful, but it may become useful if the situation is better described.

Comment: @EarlGrey "why did you not resign from the project when you realized it was not doable?" My friend, even PhD graduates have to eat.

Comment: @DanielHatton at some point is too much shit even for a PhD. As a postdoc, even more: the pay is the same as working as a waiter, with the double of the timeload. So you work 60 hours per week for a pay X. At that point is better to find a job 40h per week with the same pay, and then do a PostDoc as a hobby only.

Comment: *I actually was working both on the original project as well on my interest (but this created a huge delay in the preparation time of the original project* your boss is seeing this way: you worked for the other project on his budget, so someone got your work for free. Additionally, the project got delayed because you were not so productive. It is reasonable to expect your boss is angry with you, after discovering that you were delaying the project not because of intrinsic difficulties, but because you were spending your braintime somewhere else. Apologize, face the consequences, move on.

Comment: Do you mean that the project you did first was a prerequisite to perform your boss project? please include this information. You are not explaining properly the situation. Please focus on what happened, not on why someone did something

Comment: Please don't sabotage your posts.

Comment: @Buffy: please delete my post, there is no need to keep this underated post.

Comment: Actually, the history of the site is worth keeping. I have no power to delete your post in any case. You can flag your post for attention by moderators, however. I have some posts that are far (far) more underrated than this one. See the help center for site usage: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: You are anonymous here. There are no issues.

Comment: Note that one reason we don't like to see such sabotage or question removal is to respect those who have taken time and effort to answer the question. Other commenters have also give thought and consideration to your original question.

Comment: @Buffy: if this post is not removed then you essentially force me to remove my user. As a new user (first post), I can tell that it was not clear to me that my post cannot be removed.

Comment: @Yair: Deleting your account won’t remove the post; it will only anonymise it even further. You might as well dissociate the post from your account. Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: why to be so strict about such a terribly written question? I honestly think that it has to be mentioned to any new user on this platform that questions cannot be removed. I don't remember approving anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

From their point of view, the abusive institute provided you at minimum a table and an email and therefore they (unwillingly) supported you while working on that other revolutionary project.

If you want to be sure, ask them if you can consider yourself as being affiliated with them to publish on that revolutionary project. If they do not answer, it means that they do not want and you can go forward with your revenge plan.

Please keep in mind three things:

- revenge is a dish to be served cold;
- no one accepts a cold dish from a revengeful person;
- if I see someone serving a cold dish to someone they do not like, I think this someone is not completely intelligent.

EDIT:

> My question is in what way would you express you inconvenience.

That is a tricky question. Of course talking openly about this behavior will help future students and society, but this way you will get "retribution".
You may be ok with that, since it seems your former advisor is putting a lot of efforts in obstructing your way, so you can consider you have to find a way out of academia. You are in an inferior position of power, so a part from trying your best to get on top and when you are a professor remember not to behave this way, there is not much you can do.

If you need to express your inconvenience, just find another to invest your time and energy positively. Your advisor is not in the co-authors list, so it is already enough "retribution".
If you publish the paper without the affiliation it is a small loss for every honest person working in that institution. If there are no honest person working there ... why did you went there?

Comment: Framing every reaction as revenge is unhelpful. If one feels they have been wronged in a relationship, it's OK to say so.  If OP feels they were treated unfairly, and the abusive lab sabotaged the project rather than supported it, it's OK to reflect it on the paper.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I agree, however in OP's words *However, I left jobless due to the action of my boss, and had horrible time throughout the writing process.* there is a clear hint to seeking revenge. And honestly. it is not clear how the boss left OP jobless: when a contract expires, it expires.

Comment: @EarlGrey There are many ways in which a PI can help postdoc secure their next job - recommendations, extensions, networking. There are ways in which PI can give postdoc some space and flexibility to allow them attend interviews etc. And there are ways in which PI can make it really difficult.  Ultimately, a postdoc leaving jobless is a waste of human talent and indicates an issue (a failure?) in the current lab.

Comment: my take is "Ask them if they want the affiliation on the paper you prepared while being at that institution. If they hate you and your job so much, they will say no. If they say yes, then they were not nice, not friendly, but they hosted you so the affiliation is deserved".
@DmitrySavostyanov sure, a postdoc advisor can support finding a job, but it is different than being left jobless.